# Syntax Error in Call when param field has a reserved character

Tags: collegescorecard

While making a call to the api, if a field param has a reserved character (ex. Computer and Information Sciences, General.) the api returns an empty list (the comma inside of the major title).

I have tried using %2C to replace commas, putting my param in brackets [], putting it in quotes, adding escape characters and I cannot seem to figure out how to make the api work.

For example a query like this:

[https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools.json?fields=latest.school.name,latest.cost.tuition.in_state,latest.cost.tuition.out_of_state,latest.programs.cip_4_digit.title,latest.programs.cip_4_digit.earnings.1_yr.overall_median_earnings,latest.aid.median_debt.number.overall&api_key=xxx&latest.programs.cip_4_digit.credential.title=Bachelor's](https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools.json?fields=latest.school.name,latest.cost.tuition.in_state,latest.cost.tuition.out_of_state,latest.programs.cip_4_digit.title,latest.programs.cip_4_digit.earnings.1_yr.overall_median_earnings,latest.aid.median_debt.number.overall&api_key=xxx&latest.programs.cip_4_digit.credential.title=Bachelor%27s) Degree&latest.school.name=University of Alabama at Birmingham&latest.programs.cip_4_digit.title=Computer and Information Sciences, General.

where the last parameter's value is Computer and Information Sciences, General. does not return anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any results? I'm having the same issue, and emailed their help desk. I've tried every combo of encoding, %2C+ and %2C25 and %2c ,and nothing. Really hung up on a project rn.